# Cannot install R packages with dependencies in Linux

Tags: r, linux, installation, package

I am using Linux Mint and I am trying to install some packages from RStudio.
When I run `install.packages("Epi", dependencies= TRUE)` installation begins but a whole lot of errors occur, so much so that the messages are so long that they don't fit in the terminal.

It begins by:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-library/rlang/libs/rlang.so':
  /usr/lib/R/site-library/rlang/libs/rlang.so: undefined symbol: R_ActiveBindingFunction
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘pkgload’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/pkgload’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgload’ had non-zero exit status
```

And ends with:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppEigen.so RcppEigen.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o init.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: RcppEigen.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RcppEigen’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘cmprsk’ ...
** package ‘cmprsk’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong  -c cincsub.f -o cincsub.o
/bin/bash: gfortran: command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:191: cincsub.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cmprsk’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/cmprsk’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cmprsk’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘mstate’ ...
** package ‘mstate’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c agmssurv.c -o agmssurv.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-jbaK_j/r-base-3.6.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c mstate_init.c -o mstate_init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o mstate.so agmssurv.o mstate_init.o -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-mstate/00new/mstate/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning message:
package ‘survival’ was built under R version 4.1.1 
Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'data.table', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: This is R 3.6.3 but data.table has been installed using R 4.1.1. The major version must match. Please reinstall data.table.
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘mstate’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/mstate’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mstate’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘pkgload’, ‘waldo’ are not available for package ‘testthat’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/testthat’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘testthat’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘RcppArmadillo’ is not available for package ‘etm’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/etm’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘etm’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘testthat’ is not available for package ‘nloptr’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/nloptr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘cmprsk’, ‘etm’ are not available for package ‘Epi’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Epi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Epi’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘minqa’, ‘nloptr’, ‘RcppEigen’ are not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/lme4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘Epi’ is not available for package ‘popEpi’
* removing ‘/home/username/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/popEpi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘popEpi’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'd also should add that at the beginning there's an error with `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran`, `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llapack`.

I tried: `sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev` and `apt install libgfortran`, but this last one apparently does not exist.
This has not worked.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install gfortran gfortran-doc` then re-install R (`sudo apt install r-base r-base-dev`) and you should solve at least one of your issues

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  It did not solve the problem, though.  Now I am trying to uninstall/reinstall but  it's worse.

Comment: Perhaps: `sudo apt install gfortran-8`

Comment: You have not said whether your installation of R was running well before this. The 'Epi' package has a tone of dependencies. `Imports: cmprsk, etm, splines, MASS, survival, purrr, plyr, dplyr, Matrix, numDeriv, data.table, zoo, mgcv`. Running a function that lists all the Imports lines in all the package DESCRIPTION files of those Epi package's Imports produces 20 additional unique package names (although many of them are base or Recommended package that you should have.) You probably ought to have Rcpp (>= 0.11.4) and all of the tidyverse available.

Comment: See if this is helpful ... the error message looks rather similar: https://community.rstudio.com/t/strange-error-when-trying-to-install-packages/84041/4